# Unity 5 website game PlayerPrefs does not work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a clicker game for a website. I want to add the final thing: ability to save the game locally. I don't know how to use playerprefs but i looked all the videos and tried to create savegame and loadgame but it does not work, but everything looks to be correct. What is wrong in my savegame or loadgame?

Savegame:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SaveGame : MonoBehaviour {

    private Databasestorage database;

    public void savegame(){

        database = GameObject.Find ("PlayerCamera").GetComponent<Databasestorage> ();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("cookies", database.cookies);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();

    }
}
```

LoadGame:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LoadSaveGame : MonoBehaviour {

    private Databasestorage database;

    public void loadsavegame(){

        database = GameObject.Find ("PlayerCamera").GetComponent<Databasestorage> ();

        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("cookies")) {
            database.cookies = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cookies");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Savegame was not found. Canceling load save game.");
        }
        //if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("cookies")) {
        //  Application.LoadLevel (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cookies"));
        //} else {
        //  Debug.Log ("Savegame was not found. Canceling load save game.");
        //}
    }
}
```

Database if you want to know what it is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Databasestorage : MonoBehaviour {

    public int enabletimer = 0;
    public double checktime = 3.0;
    public double checktimereset = 3.0;

    public float cookies = 0;
    public float drink = 0;

    public Text cookiestext;

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {

        if (enabletimer == 1) {
            checktime -= Time.deltaTime;
        } else {
            cookiestext.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Cookies: " + cookies;
        }
        if (checktime <= 0) {
            cookiestext.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Cookies: " + cookies;
            checktime += checktimereset;
        }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: LoadGame does not work! (Load Save Game)**

Comment: Public void savegame and loadgame is executed(called) on BUTTON.

Comment: What exactly "does not work" mean in this case? How your actual behaviour different from observed behaviour?

Comment: Have you verified that `savegame` method actually runs?

Comment: I dont know it should all button works the same way i did with the savegame soo it works but it does nothing there is no log or anything just nothing happens when save game and load game is pressed it should show me a debuglog if the savegame did not work right? but it does not soo it does exist i think.

Comment: The button is 100% working its executing savegame and loadgame for sure.

Comment: I found the problem. LoadGame does not work (load savegame) the buttons works but the loadgame script does not. How do i fix it? (i tested it with a lot of debug logs).

Comment: What did you found? You still describe the problem as cryptic "does not work".

Comment: Ahh i am soo sorry i did not notice i was not calling the load game script it was not set on the button it somehow deleted it self when i saved my project. SOO SORRY. now it works :) everything is ok. I am very very very sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Button did not execute loadgame because it was not set. OPS